# Elastic Beanstalk: .ebextensions not copied over

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently I am trying to extend nginx configuration for my EB instance. I read through [this support document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html) but the config file in .ebextensions is not executed and my additional nginx configuration is not created in the EB instance.

**.ebextensions/proxy.config**

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      http {
        client_max_body_size 100M;
      }
```

(also tried with 000755)

**Dockerrun.aws.json**

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "***.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/***:***",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "3000"
    }
  ]
}
```

**.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml**

```
branch-defaults:
  develop:
    environment: ***
    group_suffix: null
  ...
deploy:
  artifact: artifact.zip
global:
  application_name: ***
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: ***
  default_platform: Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
  default_region: eu-central-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: null
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

I deploy and check as follows:

```
zip -r artifact.zip .ebextensions Dockerrun.aws.json
eb deploy
ls /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

But I cannot see proxy.conf there, so it's not copied during the deployment.

Folder structure in the zip file is as follows:

```
/Dockerrun.aws.json
/.ebextensions/proxy.config
```

Comment: Your .ebextensions folder needs to be inside the source.zip or you need to use Procfile. If you need more info let me know

Comment: @StefanN my folder is already inside the zip. I also confirmed that by downloading it from S3 where it's uploaded.

Comment: Great! I just noticed that the file name and path are not under quotes.  it should be `"/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":`

Comment: I tried that as well, but did not work, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you share the complete folder structure of your zip file, as it is in S3?

Comment: I updated the original question for the folder structure of zip file.

Comment: Don't you have a source code folder somewhere in your deployment?

Comment: No, I have a Dockerrun.aws.json file that has configuration for my Docker image (stored in ECR). EB pulls it from ECR, runs it and exposes the port for my use. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html

Comment: OK. Then please make sure that the indentation is correct. I remember also having issues with that before. It should be: "files:.." -> "/etc/..." 4 spaces, then "/etc/..." -> "mode:..." 4 spaces and finally "http {" should be indented only 2 spaces.